# Fatal Error: CurlException: couldn't connect to host (PHP)

Tags: php, exception, curl, host

I've been developing an automatic delivery system for my shopify website on my local machine (EasyPHP) and everything worked fine and I've done multiple tests.

I've now transferred and updated everything for my online host (hostgator) and now I'm getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 7: couldn't connect to host [url] https://pas.mob.v7.easfc.ea.com:8095/pow/auth?timestamp=' in
```

And I have no idea why.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like verifying that your host allows outgoing http connections?

Comment: @MarcB Yes. Other connections are made before it echos this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have to enable your openssl module. Otherwise you can't make a SSL connection.

You can enable the openssl module in your `php.ini`.